# Hiding duplicate text that's the same in a child div as the parent div

Tags: jquery

This is what I have:

```
<div class="outer">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>more text</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="inner">
    <table>
      <tr>
       <td>different text</td>
       <td>more text</td>
      </tr>
   </div>
</div>
```

Basically I need to search through the whole outer div and look for duplicate text. The only thing is I need to remove the first iteration of it and not the second. Another words, If it's duplicated I want to leave it in the inner div and remove it outside of it.

I have this code I've played with but can't get anywhere. I will remove the duplicate from the inner div.

```
 $('.outer td').each(function () {
           var txt = $(this).text();
           if (seen[txt])
               $(this).remove();
           else
               seen[txt] = true;
           $(this).show();
       });
```

Lil help Please... I'm exhausted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.outer td:not(.inner td)').each(function () {
        var txt = $(this).text();
        var current = $(this)
        $('.inner td').each(function () {
            if(txt == $(this).text())
            {
               current.remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5phau2sd/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```js
var seen = {};
$('.outer td').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  if (seen[txt]) {
    seen[txt].remove();
  }
  seen[txt] = this;
  $(this).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>some text</td>
      <td>more text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="inner">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>different text</td>
        <td>more text</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Marvelous! Worked perfect! Thank you!